# Formatting alpha numeric cells in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, serial-number

I use excel to correlate key credentials. My keys are in this format xxxx-xx, where 'x' can be a letter or number. Is there any way to format the cells so that I don't have to type the "-" every time? and it will sort properly?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible directly (see the documentation on [formats in Excel](https://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/create-a-custom-number-format-HP010342372.aspx)).

However, you could use a formula like `=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,4),"-",RIGHT(A1,2))` to create a formatted column.

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to the above, but in some sense "easier" to change.

WARNING, untested code; it works in <del>open</del> LibreOffice though ;-).

Press ALT-F11

Insert a module, then type this into the editor window:

```
function alphaFmt(s as string) 

   if len(s)>2 then
     alphaFmt=left(s,len(s)-2)+"-"+right(s,2)
   else 
     alphaFmt=s
   end if

end function
```

Then type:

```
=alphaFmt(VALUE)
```

in any cell, replace VALUE by either a literal string, cell reference or formula building a string.